# Why doesn't this (mysql) UNION solve my problem?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm new to sql. Basicially, I'm trying to `SUM` an amount from one table, over somekind of ID. I got that part, but I also want to know if that person is (in)active and that's from another table. I know I can use my ID, and I've tryed with a UNION, but no luck so far.

**Gives the data `p.inactive`.**

```
SELECT p.inactive
FROM deb d
    RIGHT JOIN pat p ON(d.debitor = p.cpr);
```

**`d.amount` works but `p.inactive` does not, because of the `LEFT JOIN`**

```
SELECT SUM(d.amount), p.inactive
FROM deb d
    LEFT JOIN pat p ON(d.debitor = p.cpr)
GROUP BY d.debitor;
```

**So I've tryed to combine them with a UNION, but `p.inactive` is still `null`**

```
(   SELECT d.debitor, p.inactive FROM deb d 
        LEFT JOIN pat p ON d.debitor = p.cpr
)
UNION
(
    SELECT d.debitor, p.inactive FROM deb d 
        RIGHT JOIN pat p ON d.debitor = p.cpr
    WHERE d.debitor IS NULL
);
```

I'm totally stucked now? Can anyone help? Is it even posible without seeing my DB. Let me know if I need to provide more data/info.

**---------------------- UPDATE**

**Table deb**

debitor  |  amount

1...|...10

1...|...20

1...|...45

2...|...30

2...|...10

**Table pat**

cpr...|...inactive

1...|...0

2...|...1

3...|...0

4...|...0

5...|...1

6...|...1

---

The person with p.cpr and d.debitor = 1, has a sum amount of 75 and is INACTIVE

The person with p.cpr and d.debitor = 2, has a sum amount of 40 and is ACTIVE

**Final Update:**

My bad, I assummed there was some deb.debitors in the pat.cpr, and there wasn't, hence the no matches. Next time I will test for that first ofcourse.

Comment: `p.cpr` is a foreign key to `d.debitor` or vice versa? Please provide some sample data

Comment: @radbyx `WHERE d.debitor IS NULL` is not needed in first union query?

Comment: `d.debitor` is unique? `p.cpr` is unique? Please provide some sample data and desired result so we might understand the relation between both tables.

Comment: Ups I mean it's not a primary key, but it's a foreign key. e.g. d.debitor matches the p.cpr's... If that make sence?

Comment: @RobertKock In my last query I tryed to make a UNION in mysql, that's how you are supose to make a FULL JOIN in MySql I think. But there must be something wrong with it.

Comment: I repeat: please add sample data and desired output. It's quite hard guessing this way.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a go.

Comment: @RobertKock I have updated my question with a clear example now.

Comment: In my 3rd query I followed the second query in the Accepted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: My bad, I assummed there was some deb.debitors in the pat.cpr, and there wasn't, hence the no matches. Next time I will test for that first ofcourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming debitor - cpr are joined many to one you can use your left join example but include the desired column in your GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT SUM(d.amount), p.inactive
FROM deb d
LEFT JOIN pat p ON d.debitor = p.cpr
GROUP BY d.debitor, p.inactive;
```

Or you can join after grouping (this allows you to include columns that you normally cannot use inside group by):

```
SELECT a.debitor, a.total, p.whatever
FROM (
    SELECT d.debitor, SUM(d.amount) total
    FROM deb d
    GROUP BY d.debitor
) AS a
LEFT JOIN pat p ON a.debitor = p.cpr
```

PS: If you want to eliminate NULL values from the right table then you need an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try. Debitor and cpr is not primary keys but the cpr is foreign key and debitor have the same format so you can use that too. Hopes it explain it enough, I'm new to sql and else let me know.

Comment: I think your first query looks like my second right? I can't see the different. It produces the same.

Comment: I added `p.inactive` in group by. Without it your second query would be illegal but MySQL allows it.

Comment: I've replaced "p.whatever" with "p.inactive" to your last query, but it still gives me null values.

Comment: As I see it, I still have the same problem. The issue is not the group by. It's that I can't call anything on `p` after a LEFT JOIN pat. I know that's how the LEFT JOIN work, but I want to call on both "d." and "p.".

Comment: If inactive is null then either (i) the matched record (a.debitor = p.cpr) contains NULL in that column (ii) no record matched at all. For testing, you could try adding a primary key column from pat table inside select and group by and see if it is also NULL.

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to compose something not possible or misunderstand it completely. I just think this should durable. When I run my first query, I can see all the values is either "0" or "1", there is no one with "null". The "null" must come from the join I think.

Comment: You may wanna try a `FULL JOIN`

Comment: @SalmanA when I change your last query to a RIGHT JOIN instead, it gives me the "inakt" data I want, but the "a.debitor" is null.

Comment: According to your sample data, both queries provide expected result. If you get NULL then you have deb.debitor in your data that are not present in pat.cpr.

Comment: @SalmanA I might be new to sql but I can admit my fault. I badly assummed there must have been some deb.debitor in the pat.cpr but there wasn't, I just did a test.

Answer (score 1):

So `d.debitor` is a foreign key towards `p.cpr`.
Maybe I'm missing something, but in that case the solution looks quite straightforward:

```
SELECT    pat.cpr,
          pat.inactive,
          COALESCE(SUM(deb.amount), 0) AS sum_amount
FROM      pat
LEFT JOIN deb
       ON pat.cpr = deb.debitor
GROUP BY  pat.cpr,
          pat.inactive;
```

It returns a total amount of 0 in case there's no corresponding `deb.debitor` for a specific `pat.cpr`.

Comment: The sum column is all with 0's (because the COALESCE changes the null's to 0's i guess). I'm sure you know your stuff like Salman but I don't know how to describe my case better. I spent a hour writting my question so I put alot of effort into it, but I still feel I most work on that part. I know the answers are simple for you but I need to structure the question very good and with a sample or something to make it more simple and clear for you.

Comment: Oh I have no matches in (pat.cpr = deb.debitor), I'm so sorry, my bad.